# Ruby parsing XML; nil exception

Tags: ruby, xml, string, exception, null

I've got a Ruby program that parses XML from a website and now and again it crashes when one of the elements is nil.

I've implemented the following code to handle it but it doesn't seem to work;

```
begin
    data[6]= element.elements["company_info"].elements["org_number"].text unless element.elements["company_info"].elements["org_number"].nil?

rescue
    data[6] = 'no_info'
end
```

Exception message says Can't convert nil into String. Can anyone see what the problem is here?

The offending element, when `nil`, is just an `<org_number/>`.

Comment: Could you please show us how you parse an xml and how method `elements` are defined?

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm not sure what you want to see but basicaly I'm looping through an XML document like this: xmldoc.elements.each("*//advert") do |element|

Comment: WelI was hoping to now, how this xmldoc object is being created. Have you used some gem to parse the xml?

Comment: Well I'm using REXML, require 'rexml/document'
include REXML. And Mechanize. agent=Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url) xmlBlob=page.body xmlBlob.force_encoding("UTF-8")
xmldoc = Document.new(xmlBlob)

Answer (score 0):

Change your unless statement to:

```
if element.elements["company_info"] && element.elements["company_info"].elements["org_number"] && element.elements["company_info"].elements["org_number"].text
```

Also have a look into `andand` gem. With it you could simply write:

```
data[6] = element.elements["company_info"].andand.elements["org_number"].andand.text || 'no_info'
```

In general, use nokogiri gem for xml parsing instead of writing own parser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll certainly try nokogiri next time around. Your answer seems to work as well as the previous answer, but doesn't solve the problem. I have some more work to do in pin pointing the exact source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the `unless` to:

```
unless element.elements["company_info"].elements["org_number"].text.nil?
```

You need to check if the `.text` is nil or not.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It didn't solve the problem but it might have narrowed it down a bit.

Comment: Hmm.. Thats strange. If you could share how your parser is defined then it would throw some light on your problem. Also, you can think about going for Nokogiri like BroiSatse suggested. That is one of the best option.

Comment: After finally getting time to analyze this a bit deeper, the problem here is that if text is nil then I get the error message to the effect that there is no method elements for nil.